# All the records displaying while doing a query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a php page where i have created a field called employee name where i should be able to enter the employee first name and should get data of all the employees with the same first name. I am using sql 'LIKE' function for it.

i have created the field as follows

```
<form action="list.php" method="post"> 
                <b>Employee Name</b>: <input type="text" name="term" /> 
                <input style="background-color:rgb(255,213,32)" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                </form>
```

and the query i am using is

```
$term = isset($_POST['term'])? $_POST['term'] : '';
$sql =  mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT id,territory,brand,seae,e_id,name,email,contact,exist FROM employees WHERE name LIKE '%$term%'" );
```

I am displaying the data by creating the table as follows

```
<?php
            echo "<table class='center' width='100%'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
        echo "<tr><th>Territory</th><th>SE/AE</th><th>Brand</th><th>Employee ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th><th>Exist</th><th colspan='2'>Action</th></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td> <span class="page_territory">'.$row["territory"].'</span></td>
            <td><span class="page_seae">'.$row["seae"].'</span></td>
                <td><span class="page_brand">'.$row["brand"].'</span></td>
                    <td><span class="page_e_id">'.$row["e_id"].'</span></td>
                        <td><span class="page_name">'.$row["name"].'</span></td>
                            <td><span class="page_email">'.$row["email"].'</span></td>
                                <td><span class="page_contact">'.$row["contact"].'</span></td>
                                    <td><span class="page_exist">'.$row["exist"].'</span></td>

         <td class="swMntTopMenu"><a href="edit.php?id='.$row["id"].'" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><button><div class="link"><img src="images/edit.ico" alt="EDIT" style="height:15px;width:15px"></div></button></a></td>
             <td class="swMntTopMenu"><a onClick=\'javascript: return confirm("Please confirm deletion");\' href="delete.php?id='.$row["id"].'" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><button><div class="link"><img src="images/images.jpg" alt="DELETE"style="height:15px;width:15px"></div></button></a></td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

but instead of displaying the data after i enter the value into the field the table is displaying all the data from the database before i enter the value in field. can anyone help me with this.

Comment: A side note independent of the issue you ask: sql inject possible here, you want to use parameter binding instead of string concatenation when creating your query. This is a serious security issue.

Comment: About your issue: sounds like you execute that php code right away, not only after submitting the form. Since the clause `LIKE '%%'` automatically matches _all_ records, all records are displayed.

Comment: @arkascha i gott about the security issue over here coming to this records issue is it possible for me to query in any other way to get the required results

Comment: As I wrote above: use parameter binding for your query. It is documented in the php documentation. Did you check that? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

Only do the `mysqli_query` and table rendering if `isset($_POST['term'])`.

Comment: when i set this condition i am getting following notice and warning. Notice: Undefined variable: sql  and  Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Comment: If the form has not yet been submitted, don't execute the query at all, and don't call `mysqli_fetch_array` either. Have this be a large `if` around everything, and only render the html form to ask for the name..

Answer (score 0):

> Hi here is an example base on your code. You can print information of everyone in
>   the table that has the name matching the search term. Hope this helps.

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['term']) )
    {
        include 'connection.php';
        $name = $_POST['term'];

        $sql= "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE firstname= '$name'";

        $results = mysqli_query( $connection, $sql );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results ) ) 
        {
            if ( $row['firstname'] == $name ) 
            {          //you can edit the code below to print in a nice html table format if you like
                echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['email'] . " " . $row['address'] . '<br>'; //and any other information you wish to print
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //redirect or display an error message.
    }
?>
```